# Simple Command Line Password Manager

Tags: beginner, bash

[*Kruptos*](https://gist.github.com/NonlinearFruit/7b6f72f97f0d70086f3f229fbf23850f) is a simple tool that encrypts and decrypts the `~/.kruptos` directory with the password that is stored in `~/.kruptos/.phrazein`. There are 3 commands:

- <kbd>e</kbd> - Encrypt
- <kbd>d</kbd> - Decrypt
- <kbd>i</kbd> - Initialize

#### Goal

I have a couple main goals:

- Design: How could I make this more resilient to change?
- Readability: How could I make this more readable?
- Best Practices: Are there aspects of a bash command that I am missing?

```bash
# Minimalist password manager
function kruptos
{
    # Decipher the flag
    if [[ $# -eq 1 ]]; then
        DOWHAT="$1"
    else
        DOWHAT="d"
    fi

    # Perform an action
    if [[ $DOWHAT == "d" ]]; then
        #Decrypt
        pushd . &>/dev/null
        cd ~/
        openssl aes-256-cbc -d  -in .kruptos.tar.gz.aes | tar -xz -f - --strip-components=2 && rm ~/.kruptos.tar.gz.aes
        popd &>/dev/null
    elif [[ $DOWHAT == "e" ]]; then
        #Encrypt
        tar -zcf - ~/.kruptos | openssl aes-256-cbc -out ~/.kruptos.tar.gz.aes -kfile ~/.kruptos/.phrazein && rm -r ~/.kruptos
    elif [[ $DOWHAT == "i" ]]; then
        #Initialize
        mkdir ~/.kruptos
        echo pswd > ~/.kruptos/.phrazein
    else
        echo "$DOWHAT is not an acceptable flag"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll not address the security analysis; I'll assume you've done threat modelling and are happy with the overall approach.

---

Instead of a chain of `if`/`elif` all testing the same variable, the natural approach is a switch.  I'll also take advantage of `${:-}` to default the argument:

```
case "${1:-d}" in
    d)
        # Decrypt
        # (commands)
        ;;
    e)
        # Encrypt
        # (commands)
        ;;
    i)
        # Initialize
        # (commands)
        ;;
    *)
        # invalid
        exec >&2
        echo "Usage: $0 [option]"
        echo "Options:"
        echo "  d - decrypt [default]"
        echo "  e - encrypt"
        echo "  i - initialize"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Note that I've sent the error message to error output (`&2`) and exited with an error code.  Actually, this should really be `return 1` since it's a function rather than a complete script.

---

In the decrypt code, you use `pushd` and `popd`.  These are suited to interactive use, but are best left alone in scripts or functions (that's why you discovered that you need to redirect their output).  Instead, you can use a sub-shell:

```
(cd ~; commands... )
```

or use full paths.  In this case, we want `tar` to output to `~`, and we can tell it to do so, using its `-C` option:

```
openssl -in ~/.kruptos.tar.gz.aes | tar -C ~ -xz -f -
```

---

Finally, you can avoid duplication by putting paths that are used more than once into variables.  This protects you against mis-typing any of them, and makes it easier if you should ever want to change them.

### Modified code

Here's what I have, after applying the above changes:

```
function kruptos
{
    local dir=~/.kruptos
    local file=~/.kruptos.tar.gz.aes
    local keyfile="$dir/.phrazein"

    case "${1:-d}" in
        d)
            # Decrypt
            openssl aes-256-cbc -d  -in  \
                | tar -C "$dir" xfz - \
                && rm "$file"
            ;;
        e)
            # Encrypt
            tar -C "$dir" cfz - . \
                | openssl aes-256-cbc -out "$file" -kfile "$keyfile" \
                && rm -r "$dir"
            ;;
        i)
            # Initialize
            mkdir "$dir"
            echo pswd >"$keyfile"
            ;;
        *)
            # invalid
            exec >&2
            echo "Usage: $0 [option]"
            echo "Options:"
            echo "  d - decrypt [default]"
            echo "  e - encrypt"
            echo "  i - initialize"
            return 1
            ;;
    esac
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have nothing on the scripting as such, it looks good to me. But given the subject matter, there's one big point, and two small ones:

- You're saving the decrypted data on the disk, and removing it just with a plain `rm`. That is likely to leave the decrypted data on the disk in plaintext. For a password encryptor, I think this is quite an issue, even though changing it would require a bit of restructuring. Possibly decrypt the file to a RAM-based filesystem (OS dependant), or add functionality to modify individual entries in-line.
- Initialization should perhaps ask for the password to be entered instead of setting a fixed one. (Possibly asking twice to make sure the user types it correctly.)
- My manual for `openssl` says  `-kfile $filename`  is superseded by `-pass file:$filename`

In any case, points for using `openssl` instead of hand-rolled encryption.

Comment: Hey, nice - my answer and yours complement each other, and make a complete answer between us.  Thumbs up for the team-work!